# Birt Viewer - rptlibrary file

Tags: birt

I have tried this-
   using resource window and then inserting rptlibrary to the rptdesign file and it applied successfully , but it is not reflecting to *rptdesign* files when i am doing changes in rptlibrary file from another location,Means i want to keep rptlibrary file at different location and i wants to do changes from there.

For some security issue i have to keep rptlibrary file and rptdesign files separate so how can i do this?

My problem is-
   I want to link *rptlibrary* file to my all *rptdesign* files. And i want like if i change in *rptlibrary* file so it will reflects to all *rptdesign* files. 
How can i do this ?

Please help me...

**Thanks**

Comment: It natively acts like this, i mean when a .rptlibrary is changed all .rptdesign using this library reflect the changes. If it doesn't in your case, it could mean you have overridden some properties directly in .rptdesign. If you are not sure how to check if a report element has been overridden or not, i will post an answer with a screenshot to illustrate this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my problem is when i put rptlibrary file and rptdesign in different location that time it is not working. If i place both in same folder that time it works fine.

Comment: Check the "Resource Path" under Preferences / Report Design.

Comment: I have checked it but its not working when i change DataSource url or username in rptlibrary file, its not affacting in rptdesign file. So how to do this.